# How can I detect Borderside of MouseEnter event in C#/WPF for resizing Grid Elements

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to set for each side of a border its own EventHandler for mouse-enter or mouse-leave event. For example for the Left-Border of a Grid and Top-Border of a Grid?

What I am actually trying to do is allow the user to resize Grid-Elements inside a Canvas that contain a TextBlock with the mouse.

I am inserting my Grid/Border into the Canvas with the following code:

```
Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
tb.Text = fd.LabelText;
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Background = labelBackgroundBrush;
grid.Background.Opacity = myOpactiy;
border.DataContext = fd;
grid.Children.Add(tb);
border.Child = grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example at [csharphelper.com](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/let-user-move-resize-rectangle-wpf-c/) . Although my implementation is still buggy this was a good inspiration for me. Maybe it can help others who want to do the same.